# How to check what the user set for erase/backspace in stty using c

Tags: c, linux, termios, stty

In Unix, the default setting for certain keys are different by each platform. For example, erase in Ubuntu might be `erase = ^?`. But then, for AIX, it might be totally different like example `erase = ^H`. How do I check the stty setting in C?

This is what I have tried to write

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<termios.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
  struct termios term;

  if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term) < 0)
  {
     printf("Error to get terminal attr\n");
  }

  printf("The value for Erase is %s\n",term.c_cc[ERASE]);

  return 0;
}
```

After compiling it using gcc. It says that ERASE undeclared. So what is actually the correct option or variable that I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("The value for Erase is %s\n",term.c_cc[ERASE]);` should be `printf("The value for Erase is %d\n",term.c_cc[VERASE]);`, see [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) for further details.

The symbolic index for Erase character is `VERASE`; the type of `c_cc[VERASE]` is `cc_t`, in my system, `cc_t` is `unsigned char`, so it should be printed with `%c` or `%d`.

Comment: Exactly. These are all well documented in the [`man 3 termios`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) man page. (That [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) points to [the Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/), which is in my opinion one of the most reliable sources for details such as these.)